# Jquery Mobile Collapsible content Losing Collapsible Area

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, collapsable

I am basically building dynamic collapsible content which is called when page change is done.

The creation of the collapsable content is generated on page change and populated dynamically with a number of divs. The first collapsable section is set as open (uncollapsed)

when I go to the previous page and go go back into the dynamic collapsable content page I lose the collapsable sections formatting (css)

-- I do use
$page =$(pageSelector);

Tried using - 
<strike>$page.page();
$.mobile.changePage($page);</strike> is breaking page back button.

Comment: what kind of divs are you using inside the collapsible content r u using grid or try using dynamic list inside the collapsable content that will make those list inside the those content inside collapsable.

Comment: $('#id').append('<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="c"><div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true"><h3>Code</h3><div id="barcode" class="barcode"></div></div>'); CSS for barcode -> .barcode .bar1 { border-left:1px solid black; }

Answer (score 0):

If you are appending whole Collapsible div when you append use `$("#id").append("content").trigger('create');` or you can keep the Collapsible div static and append the content like

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="c">
   <h3>Header</h3>
   <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<script>
    $("#content").append('data');
</script>
```

**Edit:**

ok i thought you were trying append content into collapsible but u were appending whole collapsible itself then u should read [this](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) documentation. As explained u have to updatelayout itself like

```
.trigger('updaelayout');
```

after appending the collapsible.

**Edit 2:**

```
<div data-role=collapsible>
   <h3>Header</h3>
    <div id="data-set" class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-c ui-corner-bottom">
    </div>
</div>
$("#data-set").append('data');
```

try this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply -- this is the setup - static content: <div id="idContainer" data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="c"></div>.This is the dynamic content: $('#id').append("<div data-role='collapsible data-collapsed='true'><h3>"+data.givenName+"</h3><div id='barcode' class='barcode'>"+data.text+"</div>").trigger('create');  I also tried - $('#idContainer').trigger("create"); Still not working

Comment: @malteseKnight coz collabsible has dynamic events in framework to hide and show contents u have to update layout itself.try the edits.

Comment: Thanks for your insights and help. Unfortunately I am still not getting lucky here. tried both trigger create and also updatelayout...

Comment: @malteseKnight ok it should work fine according to the documentation , i might have way around it like you can keep the whole collapsable as static content in the document jus add the dynamic data alone in collapsable with <ul> add data as list specify data-inset=true for list and refresh list alone the data will be inside div  this is wat i have done in my projs. I could really try if u had some jsfiddle of what u have implemented.